# How to seal molded plastic shower when repainting

Tags: bathroom, paint, caulking

In preparing to repaint my bathroom, I noticed the paint around the molded plastic shower stall was peeling and exposing the joint compound underneath. There doesn't appear to be any caulking around the seam.

[image]

After I've removed the loose paint and touched up the joint compound, what should my next step be? Should I add some caulking and then prime + paint, or prime + paint and then add caulking after? Or both?

On a side note, do I need to add anti-mildew additive to the primer, or just the color coat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seam between the surround and the wall *should* be sealed with caulking. You could repair and paint the wall, then use clear caulking at the seam, or repair the wall and seal the seam with paintable caulk then paint. Your choice.

Use a high quality paint and ensure adequate ventilation and no mildewcide is necessary. If you must use it, add it only to the topcoat.

Comment: What he said ^^, although I'm partial to silicone caulk, which isn't paintable. Be sure to figure out why the paint failed in the first place. (My guess is pooling water, either from the shower itself, or from condensation dripping down. If condensation, are you doing enough to ventilate the bath?)